# What should the transactionReceipt verification json look like?

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to verify a sandbox transactionReceipt at https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt using php and cURL.

The original receipt when it arrives at my server looks like:

```
{ "signature" = "AksOP5dmXwg 9WjlcE7PwBEFZgcqBnIb0Uv2lSKebWJJpcOZQRL6ejYyv20MzPFDSgAj3GRGoJXWZpyJLAU8qZSQFYQeGljWKZd3XTJN4j1E7fqOQRBdIXSDRJr1phB/11xp smk6m ... dgcxRHuOMZ2tm8npLUm7argOSzQ=="; "purchase-info" = "ewoJIml0ZW0taWQiID0gIj ... jAiOwp9"; "pod" = "100"; "signing-status" = "0"; }
```

*1. Should it have the equals and semicolons?*

Wrapping this up for transmission in the cURL I use:

```
$receipt = json_encode(array("receipt-data" => base64_encode($transactionReceipt)));
```

which gives:

```
{"receipt-data":"ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQ ... <lots more of the same> ... XR1cyIgPSAiMCI7Cn0="}
```

This results in: **{"status":-42023}** from Apple

If I use:

```
$receipt = json_encode(array("receipt-data" => $transactionReceipt));
```

which gives:

```
{"receipt-data":"{\n\t\"signature\" = \"AksOP5dmXwg 9WjlcE7PwBEFZgcqBnIb0Uv2lSKebWJJpcOZQRL6ejYyv20MzPFDSgAj3GRGoJXWZpyJLAU8qZSQFYQeGljWKZd3XTJN4j1E7fqOQRBdIXSDRJr1phB\/11xp smk6m ... dgcxRHuOMZ2tm8npLUm7argOSzQ==\";\n\t\"purchase-info\" = \"ewoJIml0ZW0taWQiID0gIjM3NTgyNzIyOCI7Cgkib3JpZ2luYWwtdHJhbnNhY3Rpb24taWQiID0gIjEwMDAwMDAwMDA1ODQyNDIiOwoJInB1cmNoYXNlLWRhdGUiID0gIj ... jAiOwp9\";\n\t\"pod\" = \"100\";\n\t\"signing-status\" = \"0\";\n}"}
```

I get: **{"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property list parsing failed while attempting to read unquoted string. No allowable characters were found. At line number: 1, column: 0."}**

*2. Can anyone please tell me what the receipt-data json is supposed to look like?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was banging with my head against the walls with the same problem... check this:

```
$dataToPost = json_encode(array("receipt-data" => $receivedData));
```

where **$receivedData** is the receipt base64 encoded.

Then:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $dataToPost
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt', false, $context);
```

It worked for me... give it a try and let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Unfortunately, this still gives me a {"status":-42023} response from apple, so perhaps it's the original transaction receipt that is at fault - not the code posting it to Apple.

Any chance you could post a value of $receivedData that worked for you, or at least an excerpt? Just to check the format ...

Comment: This is an excerpt of a valid receipt: "ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQXE1SW5wa2FoMmpUVmFtVDIyeE44RnNxNFFOaHdr\r\nbFkvWUxNRDBiSi9BRG1...0d0lqc0tmUT09IjsKCSJwb2QiID0gIjEwMCI7Cgkic2lnbmlu\r\nZy1zdGF0dXMiID0gIjAiOwp9"


I can send you an email with the complete receipt, if you wish...

Comment: I guess the only difference with my code is that I'm doing the base64 encode on the device and my server side page receives it, encode it to JSON and send's it to Apple

Comment: Hey Adri, That's really helpful. No need to post the full receipt just now. The fact that the \r and \n are preserved is interesting. 
Hmmmm, i'll try out doing the base64 on the phone and report back!

Comment: just wanted to say thanks for this - I was trying to get this to work for at least an hour or 2, trying different variants of how to post the data, I think the key piece I was missing was Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

This is now working for me! My final bug was that I had, in series of tests and changes, actually modified the receipt data file. Ooops :(. I had indented the receipt by 4 bytes, in preparation for submitting a post to stackoverflow of all things. Indenting the receipt made it invalid, perhaps not surprisingly.